# How to perform an excel vlookup with dynamic lookup_value using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and need to perform a `vlookup` with a dynamic `lookup_value`. The reason for this is that the actual lookup_value column can be on different column indices for different input sheets.

The original vlookup formula looks like this:

```
"=VLOOKUP(C2,lookup!$A$2:$B$14,2,FALSE)" 'static vlookup
```

What I am trying to accomplish should look like this:

**1) Find the actual column index with the lookup_value inside (in the above case it's C2)**

```
With ws
    Set FindRng = .Rows(1).Find(what:="Column Name") ' should be 3 for C
        FiltCol = FindRng.Column ' get the column number where "Column Name" was found
End With
```

**2) Set lookup_value dynamically (in this case C2)**

```
Dim dynamic_lookup_value as Range
dynamic_lookup_value = ws.Cells(FiltCol, 2) ' should be column C cell 2
```

**3) Set dynamic reference to lookup_value to actual vlookup formula (i.e. repalce hardcoded C2 with reference to C2**)

```
foobar = "=VLOOKUP(dynamic_lookup_value,lookup!$A$2:$B$14,2,FALSE)" 'dynamic vlookup
```

However, (3) yields `Run-time error '91' Object variable or With-block variable not set`.

**How to perform an excel vlookup with dynamic lookup_value using VBA?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have the columns and rows reversed here:

> `ws.Cells(FiltCol, 2)`

It should be:

```
ws.Cells(2,FiltCol)
```

Second you Set a range:

```
Set dynamic_lookup_value = ws.Cells(2,FiltCol)
```

Then you do not put variables inside the quotes but concatenate them with `&`

```
foobar = "=VLOOKUP(" & dynamic_lookup_value.Address(0,0) & ",lookup!$A$2:$B$14,2,FALSE)"
```

Another piece of advice:

> `FiltCol = FindRng.Column`

Will error if the value is not found.  Put it in an If statement to check if the value was found or not:

```
If  not FindRng is nothing Then
    ...
End IF
```

Comment: works like a charm! <The If not is nothing then> part is in my original code, I just removed it since people tend to not answer if my example code gets longer - again: thanks man

Comment: @sudonym understandable, but the next person who comes across this may not know, so I will leave it in.  Glad to have helped.